# Showing warning for filter method in React js

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, eslint, arrow-functions

I am getting a warning as **Expected to return a value at the end of arrow function  array-callback-return**

i am deleting an selected post using axios and json server , after deleting each post i am just returning the new array

```
.then(() => {
        const remainingPosts = this.props.posts.filter((post) => {
          if (post.id !== this.state.loadedPost.id) {
            return post
          }
        })
```

if i comment out the if condition i  am not getting the warning , else i am getting the warning

Comment: Its an eslint warning [the docs are here](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/array-callback-return)

Comment: Thanks wgcrouch , after the if condition i given simply return false it worked for me thanks for the link

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only need to provide a true of false condition in the filter

```
.then(() => {
    const remainingPosts = this.props.posts.filter((post) => {
      return post.id !== this.state.loadedPost.id

    })
```

or even simpler

```
.then(() => {
    const remainingPosts = this.props.posts.filter((post) => (
        post.id !== this.state.loadedPost.id   
    ))
```

Comment: i tried the above code also worked for me !! thanks for the response